# Image Overwriting Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio

Aim of my program is to take an image from SD card, pass it to a function in class CombinePhotos (along with another image) and that function will return one of the two images of type Bitmap. I've to overwrite it to the one in SD card. The following is my code, but it crashes all the time. Please help me.

```
private void combinePhotos() throws IOException {
    CombinePhotos combinePhotos = new CombinePhotos();
    Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg");
    Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sample);
    Bitmap bmFinal = combinePhotos.combine(bm1, bm2);
    File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg");
    FileOutputStream bos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg");
    bmFinal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,85,bos);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
}
```

Log:

```
08-04 16:12:29.982 2888-5972/com.garnet.dany.geooverlay E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mounted/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-04 16:12:30.652 2888-5972/com.garnet.dany.geooverlay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Camera Background
                                                                          Process: com.garnet.dany.geooverlay, PID: 2888
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.garnet.dany.geooverlay.CameraClass.combinePhotos(CameraClass.java:262)
                                                                              at com.garnet.dany.geooverlay.CameraClass.access$200(CameraClass.java:53)
                                                                              at com.garnet.dany.geooverlay.CameraClass$5.onImageAvailable(CameraClass.java:201)
                                                                              at android.media.ImageReader$ListenerHandler.handleMessage(ImageReader.java:648)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
08-04 16:12:30.702 2888-2888/com.garnet.dany.geooverlay E/AndroidCameraApi: onPause
```

Comment: Why does it crash? Do you have a crashlog?

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand anything from that.

Comment: Can you please edit it in your question above? Maybe other people will understand it.

Comment: show this function: combinePhotos.combine(bitmap1,bitmap2) - this seems to return null and seems to be the culprit here

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the logs shared, the following variable looks to be null.

```
Bitmap bmFinal = combinePhotos.combine(bm1, bm2);
```

As a result, calling a method on it is causing the crash.                                                                           `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference`

Make sure the .combine method is indeed producing a non null output.

Comment: But the .combine method is returning bm1 itself.

Comment: have you checked if bmFinal is not null ?

Comment: @DanielJames on further inspection of the logs ```08-04 16:12:29.982 2888-5972/com.garnet.dany.geooverlay E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mounted/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)``` it seems there is an error with bm1 itself. Since you mention that the combine method returns bm1, it could be that bm1 is null or not when you do ```Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/GeoOverlay/pic.jpg");```. Please check.